# ''error: line 1 has elements less than 2'' in gcta in linux

Tags: linux

I'm trying to make a GRM using GCTA https://yanglab.westlake.edu.cn/software/gcta/#MakingaGRM.

I am using genetic .bim .bed .fam style data of ~10,000 individuals. I have a .txt files of IDs of those to use to make the GRM. Here is an example of the top of the file:

```
184756782736_R06C02
847590372877_R03C02
758697857466_R03C02
102938475999_R05C01
176766475869_R08C02
398987586666_R06C02
```

I have tried ordering them as a list in a column, but also space and tab delimited. My code is [where data = data.fam and file.txt is a .txt file of IDs to retain/keep] :

```
gcta64 --bfile /data --keep file.txt --maf 0.01  --make-grm --out out_file
```

However when I run my code, I get the error:

```
Error: the subject list file [file.txt], line 1 has elements less than 2
```

I presume subject list file is the file with IDs [file.txt].

This suggests I am using the correct method so I think this must be a data/linux issue?
https://cnsgenomics.com/data/teaching/STAT7306/2019/Practical/Practical_partF.pdf

When I google it, nothing comes up.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks so much.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information. Which file is "the subject list file"? Your command contains `retain_idd.txt` and the error message mentions `file.txt`. Please show the first few lines of this file. What is the syntax for this file?

Comment: Thankyou @Bodo - I hope this is now more clear?

Comment: Is there a blank line at the very start of the file?

Comment: No, straight away IDs @Bib

Comment: Thanks all, it was an issue with the GCTA software specifically, resolved now by adding an extra column to the data.